# Findstr doesn't like spaces in variable input.

Tags: batch-file, command-line, whitespace, findstr

The Batch file below works perfect if I do not use spaces between queries in the srch string. Once I add a space the program jumps out and exits.

```
@echo off
mode con:cols=90 lines=40
:top
echo *******PHONE BOOK******
echo Press Q to quit
echo.
set /P srch=Enter Search query:
IF  /i %srch% EQU Q goto :end
findstr /i %srch%  %USERPROFILE%\documents\names.txt
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto :e1
pause
cls
goto top
pause

:end 
set /p wate=Press any key to Quit
exit


:e1
echo No match found edit names.txt in your documents folder.
pause
cls
goto top
exit
```

Save as PhoneQuery.bat

Save below as "names.txt" in your documents folder.

```
 Name               Address          Local         Phone#
 Bob Billings      123 here ST       St Paul MI    800-555-5555
 Information       nil               any           411
 Fire Dept         Multi             Dubai         +1-992-611-1212
```

Comment: `findstr /i "%srch%"  %USERPROFILE%\documents\names.txt`

Comment: The help file shows some great examples: **Use spaces to separate multiple search strings unless the argument is prefixed with /C.  For example, 'FINDSTR "hello there" x.y' searches for "hello" or "there" in file x.y.  'FINDSTR /C:"hello there" x.y' searches for "hello there" in file x.y.**

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to simply change your `findstr` line to read:

```bat
findstr/IC:"%srch%" "%USERPROFILE%\documents\names.txt"
```

Alternative using `Find`:

```bat
find /I "%srch%"<"%USERPROFILE%\documents\names.txt"
```

Comment: Update your script in the opening post to show it using my command and explain the problem again. As you have determined that my command works in the console, it is obviously your script that has the issue.

Comment: The Script as written works in the command prompt. However when placed inside a batch file it bumps out of the command line. Your way comes back with a bad  Switch "c:"

Comment: Drop the **`/L`**, I've done so in the code, additionally have you thought about dropping **`findstr`** and simply using **`find /i "%srch%"`**